# How to Solve App Center Error? - "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized" For Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android

My Xamarin.Android App runs just fine in the emulator but recently has just started to crash when a user runs it on an actual Android Device.
This Error is displayed in App Center:

> FirebaseInstanceId.get_Instance ()
>   Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process "NameOfApp". Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Some users suggested to edit my OnCreate method within my MainActivty.cs File by adding this snippet of code:

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
```

I've done this but I do not want to roll out another broken app. can you please let me know if this is the correct way to fix this error or if there are any other ways to do so.

Thanks for your time!

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!Parameter.CheckInternet())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(NoInternetActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
            return;
        }
        Helper.TrackEvent(Parameter.CategoryLoad, "home", "Main");

        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            // If there is a Network error show message
            if (Intent.Extras.ContainsKey("NetworkError"))
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Network Error, please try again", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                // If there is a link from a notification launch the appropriate activity
                string linkType = Intent.GetStringExtra("LinkType");
                string linkPage = Intent.GetStringExtra("LinkPage");
                if (linkPage.Equals("main"))
                {
                    // Link is a main page
                    LaunchMainActivity(linkType);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (linkType.Equals("video"))
                    {
                        // Link is a Youtube video
                        Helper.LaunchVideo(this, linkPage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Link is a single page
                        LaunchSingleActivity(linkType, linkPage);
                    }
                }
                // Used this at some point to debug the extras but it's not necessary
                foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
                {
                    if (key != null)
                    {
                        var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                        Helper.TrackEvent("DEBUG", "extras", $"Key: {key} Value: {value}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs from AppCenter, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm

It’s a known issue and this is what they suggest

“This is a known problem that you can work around by cleaning the solution and rebuilding the project (Build > Clean Solution, Build > Rebuild Solution).”

I would not recommend adding that code you mentioned. It will not guarantee your app will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help and response, I will soon give this a try!

Comment: Unfortunately for me I'm still getting an error through AppCenter. Please see me stack trace below, please let me know if you happen to have any other suggestions - Thanks for your time.

Comment: JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
FirebaseInstanceId.get_Instance ()
NewUpdateActivity.RunRegistration (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] categories)
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_1 (System.Object state)

Comment: @Nantourakis seems like it could be another issue too there. Could you share the code for that function call?

Comment: Thanks @Saamer , I have added the function where I'm trying to initialize Firebase

Comment: Did you try removing this line Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this); ? It’s not needed as I mentioned, so you still get an error after removing that line ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, manually configuring Firebase like below solved my issue.

```
var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.SetApplicationId("<AppID>")
.SetApiKey("<ApiKey>")
.SetDatabaseUrl("<DBURl>")
.SetStorageBucket("<StorageBucket>")
.SetGcmSenderId("<SenderID>").Build();
var fapp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);
```